# Can't figure how to use lookup() in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In the report I am building I have 2 data sets: one gives me, per user, per day, the total amount in that status; the other one gives me, per user, how many days in the date range the user actually showed up at work. Each of these data sets comes from its respective stored procedure. See screenshot.

The problem I have is that I need to report not the total time in status per user, but the average per day. So in the screenshot you can see that one user has 5 entries for 5 days worked and the other one has 3 entries for 4 days worked. simply because in one of those 4 days he didn't had that status at all.

I tried adding a calculated field to my "status" data set by using the lookup() function but it kept on giving me errors, which makes me think I don't quite know how to use it.

I also tried using group variables, and I was able to define it under group properties, but it never come up as an option to be used when writing an expression.

Any ideas using lookup(), variables or otherwise?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Sounds like the [`Lookup` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) is exactly what you want.

Instead of trying to add the calculated field to the dataset, try putting it directly in the report item where you want this displayed.

Something along these lines should work:

```
=SUM(Fields!Available.Value)
 / Lookup(Fields!UserId.Value, Fields!UserId.Value, Fields!Days.Value , "NameOfDaysDataset")
```

If this isn't working, please post a few more details of your data sets, field names, and where you need this to appear.

Comment: Great thanks! I would have thought that having it as a calculated field would make for a more elegant and maintainable solution. It never occurred to me that not working there, it would work directly in the table. Thanks again!